# The box around the post-owner's name in comments overlaps the underline of links

Tags: bug, comments, design

The box around the post-owner's name in comments overlaps the underline of links on the line above. I think this only affects MSO, I've only tested a few other sites, and I don't know if any other sites use the dotted underlines for links.

Conceivably, if the link was entirely above the username, it would be impossible to tell if it was a link or not.

Chrome, Mac.

> [image: Off by one bugs worst bugs]

Comment: [`It happens with backtick text as well`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266512/2246344) <-- actually a link.

Comment: You mean if I have a [link](http://notevenarealsite-ihope.com) above a loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong line of text with `backticked text on the line below` you wouldn't see?

Comment: I've just tried it out. No, it doesn't appear to happen. I've noticed it only happens with links that have backtick background, or, the background from the OP's name.

Comment: @Sam Interestingly though, if you do have backticked text on the same line as your post-owner box, it expands the line-height enough so that the link on the line above is not obscured!

Comment: @Sam Everyone loves off-by-one errors, especially designers!

Comment: [M.SE: Make links in comments immune to being hidden by username](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201811/make-links-in-comments-immune-to-being-hidden-by-username)